# Simultaneous X Users on same machine

Tags: linux, x-server

I've seen a few Questions for this but can't find anything useful or recent.  Is it possible to have 2 people physically sat at a linux box logged with separate monitors/kb/mice?

I've had to work late the past few days and my younger daughter is upset she has missed out on playing about with scratch.  I thought it would be good if we could have worked side by side.  I'd prefer it if she was logged under her own user.

Currently running mint rosa if that makes a difference.

Edit: As I mentioned there are older questions about this, the one quoted is 5 years old and involves a lot of tinkering and experimenting.  While I enjoyed this 18 years ago despite blowing up a rather expensive monitor due to a typo in a config file (got my refresh rate wrong), nowadays I just like to get on with my work.  I was hoping there was something more recent that made things easier.

Comment: Get her a nice Raspberry Pi of her own ;)

Comment: You mean like this? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg_multiseat

Comment: @Sukminder Thanks for that I'll take a look, looks like its been updated recently and less messign about than other articles.

Comment: @Ghanima My office is in the attic, pretty much maxed out at the sockets but this was my original thought, I could always turn something off.

Comment: assuming you have a network around the house, and probably an old laptop or something laying around, why don;t you consider using that extra pc as a vnc client ? Needless to say run VNC server on your machine.

Comment: instead of VNC, enable the XDMCP protocol in your display manager (xdm, lightdm, kdm, gdm, etc) and allow connections only from your local network.  don't forget to block XDMCP (port 177) at your firewall.

Comment: an rpi with an HDMI monitor would make a nice X Terminal / "thin client".  there's a video describing how to set this up for ubuntu at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fz-JPVTJwHw